# Using Custom class instead of User class in spring security for encoding and password authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security .I have Android `application and JAVA as back end` service.Customer Service has been exposed via `REST`.

My requirement is to encode the password for customer and save it into the database while sign up process and later I can authenticate it using Spring Security in java backend. All the Customer data is feeded in JSON format from android while sign up and login process

I have seen that Spring has its own `User` and `UserService` class for authentication purpose.

I have a requirement to use Customer class instead of USER(Spring provided bean) class.Customer Bean is having password as a field . Is there any way to use our own class and table in spring security? How can i decode the password and later authenticate while login ? please shed some light over it as i have tight requirement not to use User class of spring

**Customer  Bean**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CustomerWrapper {

    @XmlElement
    protected Long id;

    @XmlElement
    protected String firstName;

    @XmlElement
    protected String lastName;

    @XmlElement
    protected String emailAddress;
    @XmlElement
    protected String username;

    @XmlElement
    protected String primaryPhone;

    @XmlElement
    protected String secondaryPhone;

    @XmlElement
    protected String password;

    @XmlElement(name = "customerAddress")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "customerAddress")
    protected List<AddressWrapper> customerAddress = new ArrayList<AddressWrapper>();

setter and getter
```

Comment: what are you exactely interested in? How to save passwrrd, how to log in? I have a Spring application using my own User class.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth actually i want to encode the password first then later authenticate it using spring security for login process

Answer (score 1):

yes it's possible to use your own user class (`MyUser` in my example). What you need:

Your custom `MyUserService` must implement `UserDetailsService`, which forces you to implement `loadUserByUsername`:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    MyUser user = myUserRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        String msg = String.format("UserAccount '%s' not found.", username);
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(msg);
    }
    // assign authorities to the user:
     Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_REGISTERED"));

    User springUser = new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    return springUser;
}
```

In the above code, you return a Spring-specific user, but you will not need to work with it, it's just for the authentication manager.

in your xml config you need to connect your `MyUserService` with Spring's `AuthenticationManager`:

```
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" c:strength="12" />
<!-- manager responsible for loading user account with assigned roles -->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserService">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

To log in (i.e. to authenticate a user), you need to do something like this (I put this in my `AuthenticationService`:

```
public boolean login(String username, String password) {
    try {
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        logger.warn("User {} tried to log in with bad credentials", username);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        logger.error("An error occured during login of user {}", username, t);
    }
    return false;
}
```

To get your currently loggedIn `MyUser`:

```
public MyUser getLoggedInMyUser()  {
    try {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            return myUserService.findByUsername(auth.getName());
        }
        return null;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        logger.error("An error occurred while getting logged in User.", e);
        logout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to extend UserDetailsService from spring framework and to create a custom CustomerUserDetails that will create a User from a Customer

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService // here it's your CustomerService 
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    UserDetails userDetails = null;
    Customer customer = custermerService.login(username);
    userDetails = new CustomerUserDetails(customer);
    return userDetails;
}
```

The class *CustomerUserDetails* should extends *User*, or implement *UserDetails* from spring and create a corresponding User. Basically it will need a username, password and GrantedAuthorities

```
public class CustomerUserDetails implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails{
//must provide here username, password and GrantedAutority
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but is it possible that without extending the UserDetails or User class  of spring i can directly use my customer class for password encoding and authentication while login

Comment: No you can not use just your Customer class, because inside, spring security works with User, UserDetails and UserDetailsService (that is why CustomerUserDetails should implements UserDetails, there si where you construct a user from a customer). You have to stick with them. Think of them as a contract between your application and spring security framework.